# onfocus remove text from textarea

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have looked on google to find a way to remove text on focus but couldn't figure our how to add it back if nothing was typed in the field.

This is what I have so far...

```
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name*') { this.value = ''; }" value="Name*"
```

This will remove the "Name*" but then it is completely removed for good even if I don't type in the field.

Comment: Add an onblur that replaces the string if the value is empty. Same concept as removing it on focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the onblur event, with a similar if statement saying if it equals nothing then this.value should equal my place holder text.

```
onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name*';}"
```

[onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery

```
$("textarea").focus(function() {

    if( $(this).val() == "Name*" ) {
        $(this).val("");
    }

});
```